# Create unique random numbers (UUIDs) in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, random, uuid

I want to create random unique numbers (UUIDs) as the following

```
node.id=ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff
```

First I tried this

```
$ rndnum=` echo $RANDOM"-"echo $RANDOM"-"echo $RANDOM"-"echo $RANDOM"-"echo $RANDOM`

$ echo $rndnum
30380-echo 21875-echo 14791-echo 32193-echo 11503
```

What is the right way to create the following (where `f` is any number)?

```
ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff
```

Comment: Random numbers are not necessarily unique.

Comment: yes , seems , this number is from presto configuration ( http://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html )

Comment: Note that UUIDs are not just random numbers stringed together.

Comment: I've spent too many hours debugging scripts which assume "unlikely" is the same as "won't happen".  If this is supposed to be a UUID then please do use an actual UUID, there are strict constraints on the way they are generated.  If you could elaborate the reason you need this we might be able to help more.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

On Linux, the `util-linux`/`util-linux-ng` package offers a command to generate UUIDs: `uuidgen`.

```
$ uuidgen
5528f550-6559-4d61-9054-efb5a16a4de0
```

To quote the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uuidgen):

> The  uuidgen  program  creates  (and prints) a new universally unique identifier (UUID) using the `libuuid`(3) library.  The new UUID can reasonably be considered unique among all UUIDs created on the local system, and among UUIDs created on other systems in the past and in the future.
>
> There are two types of UUIDs which uuidgen can generate: time-based UUIDs and random-based UUIDs.  By default uuidgen will generate a random-based UUID  if  a high-quality random number generator is present.  Otherwise, it will choose a time-based UUID.  It is possible to force the generation of one of these two UUID types by using the `-r` or `-t` options.

Addendum: The OP had provided a link in the comments to [the documentation for Presto DB](http://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html). After a bit of searching, I found [this related discussion](https://github.com/prestodb/presto-admin/issues/329) where it is explicitly mentioned that the `node.id` property is indeed a UUID.

---

Adding the information provided by frostschutz in a comment:

As an alternative to the `uuidgen`/`libuuid` approach, you can make use of an interface exposed by the Linux kernel itself to generate UUIDs:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid
00db2531-365c-415c-86f7-503a35fafa58
```

The UUID is re-generated on each request.

Comment: The final touch would be `printf 'node.id=%s\n' "$( uuidgen )"`

Comment: well done , this is very good answer

Comment: possible fallback if uuidgen is unavailable: `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid`

Comment: @frostschutz that's much better -- that should've been the answer

Comment: @frostschutz I have added the information on this kernel interface to my answer. Thank you.

Comment: You saved me all the headaches, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As @frostschutz mentioned, you can use a dependency-free solution:

```bsh
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid
```

or save variable

```bsh
UUID=$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid)
```

In Bash you could simplify to:

```bsh
UUID=$(< /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid)
```

Answer (score 1):

On a raspberry PI, and probably others, the command is simply:

`uuid`

It should be preinstalled, but if not, this should do it:
`sudo apt install uuid`

Comment: I think you perhaps mean Raspberry PI OS (AKA Raspbian).  Remember that a Raspberry Pi can run many different operating systems.

Answer (score -1):

Below is bash script to generate UUID version 4 according to [RFC 4122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122).

UUID version 4 means it is based on Truly Random or Pseudo-Random Numbers.

```
#! /bin/bash

printf "%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x\n" \
$RANDOM $RANDOM \
$RANDOM \
$(($RANDOM & 0x0fff | 0x4000)) \
$(($RANDOM & 0x3fff | 0x8000)) \
$RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM
```

*$(($RANDOM & 0x0fff | 0x4000))* - replaces the left four random bits with *0100* as defined by parts [4.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122#section-4.4) and [4.1.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122#section-4.1.3) of RFC.

*$(($RANDOM & 0x3fff | 0x8000))* - replaces the left two random bits with *10* as defined by part [4.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122#section-4.4) of RFC.

Comment: I have to assume you did not read any of the answers where it is documented that a UUID is not a set of random numbers strung together and that give pointers to interfaces specifically designed to generate unique UUIDs.

Comment: You are right.
I adjusted script to fix problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @mashuptwice I have checked once more and don't see any mistakes. I also added bit operations explanations. Furthermore I looked into source code of libuuid and they use identical operations:
https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/3cfba7d39b66eff4307218fefd8bb34bb1621f83/libuuid/src/gen_uuid.c#L608
If you still see a problem please say what exactly is wrong.